# c# why wont this display to label

Tags: c#

I want to be able to display balance to label and my code is not working. This is code I got so far:

```
SqlDataReader readdata;

{
    sqlCommandbalance.Connection.Open();
    sqlCommandbalance.Parameters["@accountID"].Value = show.accoundID;
    readdata = sqlCommandbalance.ExecuteReader();
    string balanceDB = null;
    while (readdata.Read())
    {
        balanceDB = readdata["balance"].ToString();
    }
    sqlCommandbalance.Connection.Close();
    balanceShow.Text += " " + balanceDB.ToString();
}
```

On this line - `balanceShow.Text += " " + balanceDB.ToString();` got a error saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you sure your data reader returns any rows?

Comment: WinForms, WebForms, Console, Silverlight?

Comment: `balanceShow` is a label object on your user interface? The error is indicating that object has not been initialized. If you set a breakpoint on that line is this true? Are you creating the label at runtime?

Comment: @jrummell - In the context of the code, does it matter?

Comment: Since `balanceDB` is initialized to null, no. But if the `balanceShow` control was null, it might matter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're calling `balanceDB.ToString()`, when `balanceDB` will be null if the data reader contains no rows.

Note that `balanceDB.ToString()` is redundant, since `balanceDB` is already a string.  Just take out the `ToString` call.

You could also initialize balanceDB as

```
string balanceDB = "";
```

Comment: Chances are that `balanceDB` never gets assigned to (and since it is initialized to `null`, the redundant call to `ToString()` is causing the exception).

Comment: I managed to fix the problem i was sending the wrong value from form1 to form2. my code is working prefect but how would i add 2 parameter together for e.g add balance and overdraftLimit together

Answer (score 6):

Originally you set `balanceDB = null;`.

If no data was found, then no assignment will be made to `balanceDB` in the `while` loop, so it stays undefined.

Answer (score 6):

It's because of `string balanceDB = null;`

Set that to `string balanceDB = string.Empty;` and you should be OK

Answer (score 0):

Readdata.read probably returned false, making the while to never run. Thus balanceDB is still null.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query is returning an empty set. You should check for that before you set the balanceShow.Text:

```
if (balanceDB != null) {
    balanceShow.Text += " " + balanceDB.ToString();
} else {
    // tell the user that id: show.accoundID has no balance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your code is returing null in dataRader and consequentily you're tanking an null value on balanceDB. I recomend you do something like this:

```
public static string GetBalance() {

   string result = string.Emtpy;
   using (var connection = /* Build your SqlConnection */) {
      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("your select command here", connection) {
         try 
         {
            connection.Open();
            // you don't need a reader to take just a single value
            object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if (value != null) 
               result = value.ToString();
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
            /* you've got an error */
         }         
         finally 
         {
            connection.Close();
         }         
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

and in your page:

```
string balance = GetBalance();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(balance))
   balanceShow.Text += string.Contat(" ", balance);
```

if you wish to concat the balanceShow label, use '+=' operator, instead of this you just '='.

PS: Sorry for my english!